# Retrofit 2: Parsing XML data present inside XML tag

Tags: android, xml, soap, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to parse data from SOAP API using retrofit2 in my android application. But the problem is data is not getting parsed as the parsing process is not identifying the tags as they are included in the response as the value of another tag in the form of plain text.

I have created the corresponding model classes and annotated properly, but the parsing is not happening till now. Please find the WSDL of the response envelope below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <MyResponse xmlns="http://www.mywebserver.com/Webserver/">
      <MyResult>string</MyResult>
    </MyResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Inside the **MyResult** tag I was expecting the whole result in the form of XML but as the WSDL shows the XML data coming in the form of '**String**' hence the parser can't identify the tags present inside **MyResult** tag.

I used the following dependencies in my project.

```
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0"
implementation ('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.1.0'){
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax'
    exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
}
```

And my retrofit instance initialization is :

```
object RetrofitInstance {

val retrofit: Retrofit by lazy {

    val startergy = AnnotationStrategy()
    val serializer = Persister(startergy)
    val gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()

    val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()

    Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://www.mywebserveraddress.com")
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create(serializer))
        .build()
}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Adding the model classes for further reference

```
@Root(name = "soapenv:Envelope")
@NamespaceList({
        @Namespace(reference = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope", prefix = "xsi"),
        @Namespace(reference = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", prefix = "xsi"),
        @Namespace(reference = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", prefix = "xsd")
})

public class ResponseEnvelope {

    @Element(name = "Body")
    private Body body;
}


@Root(name = "Body", strict = false)
public class Body {

    @Element(name = "GetDynamicReportsResponse")
    GetDynamicReportsResponse getDynamicReportsResponse;
}


@Root(name = "GetDynamicReportsResponse")
@Namespace(reference = "http://www.server.com/MobileWebServer/")
class GetDynamicReportsResponse {
    @Element(name = "GetDynamicReportsResult")
    GetDynamicReportsResult getDynamicReportsResult;
}

@Root(name = "GetDynamicReportsResult" , strict = false)
class GetDynamicReportsResult {

    @Element(name = "reports", required = false)
    Reports reports;
}


@Root(name = "reports", strict = false)
public class Reports {

    @ElementList(name = "report", required = false)
    ArrayList<Report> reports;
}


@Root(name = "report", strict = false)
public class Report {

    @Element(name = "serviceName", required = false)
    public String serviceName;

    @Element(name = "name" , required = false)
    public String name;

    @ElementList(name = "sections" , required = false)
    public List<Section> sections;

    @Element(name = "IsPropertyChecked" , required = false)
    public String isPropertyChecked;

    @Element(name = "CheckElementId" , required = false)
    public String checkElementId;

    @Element(name = "DynamicReportCheckCycleId" , required = false)
    public String dynamicReportCheckCycleId;

    @Element(name = "CheckOptional" , required = false)
    public String checkOptional;

    @Attribute(name = "id" , required = false)
    public String id;

    @Attribute(name = "mandatory" , required = false)
    public String mandatory;

    @Attribute(name = "serviceId" , required = false)
    public String serviceId;

}


@Root(name = "section", strict = false)
public class Section {

    @Element(name = "label" , required = false)
    public String label;

    @Element(name = "questions" , required = false)
    public List<Question> questions;

    @Attribute(name = "id" , required = false)
    public String id;

}

@Root(name = "question", strict = false)
public class Question {

    @Element(name = "label" , required = false)
    public String label;

    @Element(name = "dataType" , required = false)
    public DataType dataType;

    @Element(name = "mandatory" , required = false)
    public String mandatory;

    @Element(name = "followUpInputStyle" , required = false)
    public FollowUpInputStyle followUpInputStyle;

    @Element(name = "checkElementId" , required = false)
    public String checkElementId;

    @Element(name = "visitOutcomeId" , required = false)
    public String visitOutcomeId;

    @Attribute(name = "id" , required = false)
    public String id;

    @Attribute(name = "followUpInput" , required = false)
    public String followUpInput;

}

@Root(name = "dataType",strict = false)
public class DataType {

    @ElementList(name = "options" , required = false)
    public List<Option> options;

    @Attribute(name = "id" , required = false)
    public String id;

    @Attribute(name = "name" , required = false)
    public String name;

    @Attribute(name = "type" , required = false)
    public String type;

    @Attribute(name = "minRange" , required = false)
    public String minRange;

    @Attribute(name = "maxRange" , required = false)
    public String maxRange;

}


@Root(name = "option", strict = false)
public class Option {

    @Element(name = "value" )
    public String value;

    @Element(name =  "visitOutComeId")
    public VisitOutComeId visitOutComeId;

    @Element(name = "id")
    public String id;

}


@Root(name = "visitOutComeId", strict = false)
public class VisitOutComeId {

@Element(name = "xmlns:p10")
public String xmlnsP10;

@Element(name = "p10:nil")
public String p10Nil;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML's magic lies all within the correct annotation of your data class. I struggled a lot with setting this up correctly as well.

If you could provide the annotated data class you use, I can try to help you.

Also, make sure to check out the official documentation: [it has a lot of examples and tutorials](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php).

Comment: Hi @Erwin, included annotated data class for further references.